# Take an exam and paste in line

Tags: bash, shell

I have some issue regarding data processing using shell script. I have data like this

```
Instance: A
    x.x.x.x rmt up
    x.x.x.x rmt down
    x.x.x.x rmt up

Instance: B
   x.x.x.x up
```

I want to output using shell script like this

```
A x.x.x.x rmt up
A x.x.x.x rmt down
A x.x.x.x rmt up
B x.x.x.x rmt up
```

I was trying but result no as expected:

using    `cat temp grep -i instance | sed 's/.*:  //' : result only`
A
B

Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a task for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '$1 == "Instance:"{val=$2;next} NF{$1=$1; print val, $0}' file
A x.x.x.x rmt up
A x.x.x.x rmt down
A x.x.x.x rmt up
B x.x.x.x up
```

Note that `$1=$1` re-arrange the exceeded spaces

Comment: Hi Gilles,
Thanks a lot, yes correct the command clear as my expected. last time I trying using awk but not success full

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` for this:

```bash
awk '/^Instance/ {ins = $2; next} NF {print ins,$1,$2,$3}' file

A x.x.x.x rmt up
A x.x.x.x rmt down
A x.x.x.x rmt up
B x.x.x.x up
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava,
thanks for your sollution, that is great and work as expected, but the command still produce more space

Comment: I had to edit your question to get the right formatting shown and it was't clear what spaces are required in output. Anyway I have edited my answer to make sure all fields are single spaced.